# tensorflow GPU is not available

Tags: python, tensorflow

I followed through Jeff Heaton's youtube video to install tensorflow with GPU. I have Eva nivida GTX 1660 Ti. After that, it show GPU is not available. any suggestion if something goes wrong? Thanks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnK1jO2kXOQ&list=PLrx-l85_irc5IQhZ-yOLq6NjV7GajbT0h&index=8&t=86s
https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install/tensorflow-install-jul-2020.ipynb

```
# What version of Python do you have?
# What version of Python do you have?
import sys

import tensorflow.keras
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import tensorflow as tf

print(f"Tensor Flow Version: {tf.__version__}")
print(f"Keras Version: {tensorflow.keras.__version__}")
print()
print(f"Python {sys.version}")
print(f"Pandas {pd.__version__}")
print(f"Scikit-Learn {sk.__version__}")
gpu = len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))>0
print("GPU is", "available" if gpu else "NOT AVAILABLE")
```

```
Tensor Flow Version: 2.3.0
Keras Version: 2.4.0

Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas 1.2.0
Scikit-Learn 0.23.2
GPU is NOT AVAILABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow requires CUDA to be installed to utilize a GPU. Unfortunately, the 1660 Ti is not a 
[CUDA-enabled GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). This means that you can't use tensorflow with GPU acceleration.

If you want to use a gpu, you can use a free one with [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) or [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/).

Comment: Thanks DapperDuck, so RTX 2060 support Cuda. if so, I will order one RTX 2060. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: The RTX 2060 does indeed have CUDA enabled, *however*, that is an older series of graphics card, and the new 30 series GPUs are much faster, and have more tensor cores. The 30 series cards are in high demand, and there is low stock because of scalpers. So, I would recommend using one of the online notebooks for now, and buying a new GPU after there is more stock.

Comment: Thanks DapperDuck for your good suggestion. I will wait for 30 series. Indeed, I cannot buy any one above 2060. I have been looking for it since last Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow uses CUDA, which the 1660 Ti does not support. Here is a list of all supported gpus: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Unfortunately, you can not run tensorflow with gpu-acceleration on that machine. :(

Comment: Armadillian, I checked the other website again, it say 1660 Ti does have Cuda,  https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/technologies/cuda/supported-gpus/  the other website is:  https://www.theverge.com/2019/2/22/18235974/nvidia-geforce-gtx-1660-ti-price-release-date-specs-features

Comment: "CUDA cores" is just what Nvidia calls their cores, since they do in fact use the CUDA framework to parallelize execution, but not all of their GPU's allow you to directly assign workloads to them through that framework. 1660 Ti does not.